# How to retrieve the year from a Unix timestamp?

Tags: scala

I am using `nscala-time` for scala 2.11:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The goal is to retrieve the year from a Unix timestamp:

```
val t = "1320904800"
val dt = new DateTime(timestamp.toLong)
dt.getYear.toString
```

The problem is that it outputs 1970 instead of 2011. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` constructor assumes **millisecond** value, and it seems like your input is in seconds (i.e. seconds since `1970/01/01 00:00:00.0`) - you should get the right result if you multiply by 1000:

```
val t = "1320904800"
val dt = new DateTime(t.toLong * 1000)
println(dt.getYear.toString) // 2011
```